# "Лагеря" или "лагери"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Почему везде говорят и пишут "лагеря", а не "лагери"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Форма **лагери** употребляется, если слово имеет значение '*общественно-политическая группировка; течение, направление*'.

Answer (score 2):

На сайте Грамота.ру вот такое объяснение:

> Множественное число слова лагерь зависит от значения. Если лагерь в значении 'общественно-политическая группировка; течение, направление', правильно в именительном падеже мн. числа только лагери. В других значениях верно: лагеря (и в некоторых случаях допустимо лагери). Поэтому: исправительно-трудовые лагеря.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=289288

Comment: Что это «объяснение» добавляет к ответу olsa от 10 апр '12?

Comment: Ссылку на достоверный источник

Comment: Тем не менее этот ответ сочли полезным уже два человека. Меня не удовлетворил ответ olsa, я нашел свой и поделился им здесь. Насколько мне известно, это не нарушает правил сайта. А вот ваши придирки мне непонятны.

Comment: Мне кажется, это несколько искаженное понимание. Ответы должны быть полезны не только автору вопроса, но и остальным пользователям, именно для этого есть стрелочки вверх и вниз возле каждого ответа. Вместо разведения флуда в комментариях вы можете воспользоваться этой стрелочкой, если вам ответ показался бесполезным. Если же вы считаете ответ нарушающим правила сайта, вы можете привлечь внимание модератора ссылкой "тревога".

Answer (score 0):

Где - везде?
У слова "лагерь" два значения. В значении "стоянка", "местопребывания" (пионерский, например) множественное число - лагеря.